# Nested fields and partitioning in MongoDB to BigQuery template

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to use `MongoDB to BigQuery` dataflow template and I have 2 questions:

1. Can I somehow configure **partitioning** for the destination table? For e.g. if I want to dump my database every day?
2. Can I map **nested fields** in MongoDB **to records** in BQ **instead of columns with string values**?
   I see `User option` with values `FLATTEN` and `NONE`, but `FLATTEN` will flatten documents for 1 level only.
   May any of these two approaches help?:

   - Create a destination table with structure definition before running dataflow
   - Using UDF

I tried to use [MongoDB to BigQuery dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/mongodb-atlas-and-bigquery-dataflow-templates) with `User option` set to `FLATTEN`.

Comment: Did you make this work? I tried with the first option and it did not work. I do not know how useful is to import data with NONE

Comment: @tufac2 No, I don't. But I wrote [article](https://jakubpradzynski.pl/posts/quick-dump-mongodb-to-bigquery-using-dataflow/) how to use it and work with `JSON` columns on BigQuery.

Comment: I could not try. However that solution I don't think will work because my connections to the Mongo Atlas are secured by IP. I am unable to find the IP that this Dataflow is using.

The option of opening the connection to public is not an option.